# how to mark or id a jvectormap

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

How do I mark or identify a jvectormap, so I can invoke a change in functions out of the item?
In my case, I have a jvectormap and a button(out of the map), I want it happens like when I click the button, the jvectormap's "markersSelectable" can be changed to true:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form><input id="pan" type="button" value="Pan" /></form>
  <div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#world-map').vectorMap(
        map: 'world_mill_en'
      );
      $('#pan').click(function() {
       //change the jvectormap attribute "markersSelectable" to true 
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to empty the element and reload it with the new attribute. In my experience it works well.

```
  <script>
        $(function(){
          $('#world-map').vectorMap(
            map: 'world_mill_en'
          );
          $('#pan').click(function() {
            var map_object = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            map_object.params.markersSelectable = false;
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Btw, there's a 1.2.2 version you might want to use.

Comment: Thanks, it works, however in my case, I have lots of other content in vectormap, so I'd rather not to reload the map by typing the code a second time. Sorry for not clarifying the case clearly.

Comment: @YY1988 Check out my edit and see if it works for you.

Comment: Amazing, it's working gracefully! Thank you so much!

Comment: @YY1988 No worries, glad to help. Good luck with the project!